# Arquivo Binário SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query

como realizo o download das imagens, conteúdo, arquivos que são armazenados diretamente no banco de forma binária? Pergunto isso, pois estou em uma migração de dados e o layout (planilha em excel) do novo sistema pede o caminho do arquivo, então, a ideia seria realizar o download desses arquivos e jogar para uma pasta específica.

Abaixo o select da tabela com as informações, bem como um exemplo de saída dos dados.

**Consulta**

```
SELECT [id]
    ,[file_name]
    ,[file_content]
FROM service_req_files
WHERE ID = 1073
```

**Exemplo de Saída**

> ```
> ID      file_name       file_content
> 1073    image001.png    0xFFD8FFE000104A4649460001010100...
> ```

Comment: Cara, me parece que isso não é trabalho do banco. É muito mais fácil usar uma linguagem de programação para fazer isso, embora o `SQL Server` consiga realizar a tarefa também

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar um script T-SQL como o do exemplo:

```
USE AdventureWorks;



-- Create image warehouse for importing image into sql database

CREATE TABLE dbo.ImageWarehouse (

  ImageWarehouseID INT    IDENTITY ( 1 , 1 )    PRIMARY KEY,

  ImageName        VARCHAR(100),

  Photo            VARBINARY(MAX))

GO



-- SQL Server import image - sql storing images database sql server

INSERT INTO dbo.ImageWarehouse

           ([ImageName])

VALUES     ('5THAVE.JPG')



UPDATE dbo.ImageWarehouse

SET    Photo = (SELECT *

                FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\image\photo\5THAVE.JPG',

                       SINGLE_BLOB) AS x)

WHERE  [ImageName] = '5THAVE.JPG'

GO



-- Check table population

SELECT *

FROM   dbo.ImageWarehouse

GO



-- SQL Server export image

DECLARE  @SQLcommand NVARCHAR(4000)



-- Keep the command on ONE LINE - SINGLE LINE!!! - broken here for presentation

SET @SQLcommand = 'bcp "SELECT Photo FROM AdventureWorks.dbo.ImageWarehouse"

                   queryout "e:\image\photo\exp5THAVE.jpg" -T -n -SPROD\SQL2005'



PRINT @SQLcommand -- debugging



EXEC xp_cmdshell   @SQLcommand

GO

------------

-- T-SQL Export all images in table to file system folder

-- Source table: Production.ProductPhoto  - Destination: K:\data\images\productphoto\

------------



USE AdventureWorks2008;

GO



DECLARE  @Command       VARCHAR(4096),   -- dynamic command

         @PhotoID       INT,

         @ImageFileName VARCHAR(128)



DECLARE crsImage CURSOR  FOR             -- Cursor for each image in table

SELECT ProductPhotoID,

       LargePhotoFileName

FROM   Production.ProductPhoto

WHERE  LargePhotoFileName != 'no_image_available_large.gif'



OPEN crsImage



FETCH NEXT FROM crsImage

INTO @PhotoID,

     @ImageFileName



WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) -- Cursor loop 

  BEGIN

-- Keep the bcp command on ONE LINE - SINGLE LINE!!! - broken up for presentation

    SET @Command = 'bcp "SELECT LargePhoto FROM

    AdventureWorks2008.Production.ProductPhoto WHERE ProductPhotoID = ' +

    convert(VARCHAR,@PhotoID) + '" queryout "K:\data\images\productphoto\' +

    @ImageFileName + '" -T -n -SYOURSERVER'



    PRINT @Command -- debugging 

/* bcp "SELECT LargePhoto FROM AdventureWorks2008.Production.ProductPhoto

WHERE ProductPhotoID = 69" queryout

"K:\data\images\productphoto\racer02_black_f_large.gif" -T -n -SYOURSERVER

*/



    EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command     -- Carry out image export to file from db table



    FETCH NEXT FROM crsImage

    INTO @PhotoID,

         @ImageFileName

  END  -- cursor loop



CLOSE crsImage

DEALLOCATE crsImage

/*output

NULL

Starting copy...

NULL

1 rows copied.

Network packet size (bytes): 4096

Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 16     Average : (62.50 rows per sec.)

NULL

.....

*/

------------
```

Você pode ter mais referências em:

[Neste link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5e4ae936-aff6-4d8c-b0c9-350c4e1199a7/convert-binary-image-to-jpg-image-using-sql?forum=transactsql)

[Exemplo dado acima](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/importimage/)

[Este também, porém mais complexo](https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=101754)